# Problems when parsing headers from Apple Mail sent emails

Tags: python, email, parsing, email-headers

I got an Python script that parses emails and extracts various things like headers, SHA's of attachments and such. This works most of the time but I have recently ran into a weird thing.

If the email is sent from Apple Mail I don't seem to be able to extract all the headers. So far the only times I see this is if I find the `x-mailer:` header to contain some version of Apple Mail.

I grab the emails straight from a IMAP server so they're all stored in the same way on the server as well.

The code I use - minus grabbing from email server etc - are as follows:

```
import email
from email.parser import HeaderParser

# Some stuff to grab in the email from the IMAP server
# Once grabbed, the email is stored as an 'string' object with the name of message

parser = HeaderParser()
headers = parser.parsestr(message, headersonly=True)
```

This works perfectly on all emails from all other, as far as I can see, email clients but Apple Mail seems to be different.

It looks like it just disregards some of the headers because it's not like it drops after a certain number of them or anything, it's a bit in the middle and them some random ones on top of that.

Is there any specific tricks to parsing emails that are sent from Apple Mail or is it a case of raising an exception and parsing these manually?

Any ideas or previous experiences out there?